# How does ASP.Net MVC ActionLink Work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write my own LightWeight MVC for .Net 2.0 using *NHaml* as the view engine.

In ASP.Net 3.5 MVC the View file we used to specify the link by the code snippet.

```
Html.ActionLink("Add Product","Add");
```

In MVC binary there is no function to match this call.

**I Only found:**

*(In class System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions )*

```
public static string ActionLink(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
   string linkText, string actionName)
```

There are more similar static classes like `FormExtensions`, `InputExtensions` etc.

How does ASP.Net MVC handle it? Does it generates dynamic code for Html.ActionLink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ActionLink` method is an extension method (hence the `this` before the type of the first parameter). This means you can use this method as an instance method on all `HtmlHelper` instances, even though it is not defined on `HtmlHelper`.

`Html` is a property on the View of type `HtmlHelper`. This means you can use the `ActionLink` extensionmethod on it.

The `ActionLink` method itself does nothing more than generate a link string (with regards to its arguments) and return that string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home) on Codeplex? The MVC Framwork is open source, so you can dig around as much as you need to.